# How to fix MySQL reinstallation failure in the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, mysql

I've tried removing and installing MySQL several times and I always get the same message:

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.61-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                      Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

[image]

When I try to start the service, I get the following message:

**Mysql command**

```
root@falcon:~# mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

**Mysqladmin command**

```
root@falcon:~# sudo mysqladmin root root
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
```

When listing the files in the "`/var/run/mysqld`" directory I realized that it is empty.

**Mysql error log:**

```
root@falcon:~# cat /var/log/mysql/error.log
ERROR: 1005  Can't create table 'tmp_db' (errno: 13)
180916 22:22:50 [ERROR] Aborting

180916 22:22:50 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

180916 22:22:50 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
180916 22:22:50 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
180916 22:22:50 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
180916 22:22:50 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
180916 22:22:50 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
180916 22:22:50 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/tmp/ibr58D1n' (Errcode: 13)
180916 22:22:50  InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
180916 22:22:50 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
180916 22:22:50 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
180916 22:22:50 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
180916 22:22:50 [ERROR] Aborting

180916 22:22:50 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

I have searched for this problem, but nothing worked for me. Please help.

Comment: try with type `sudo dpk-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5 ` and change your password sir

Comment: Hello abu-ahmed al-khatiri, I took the test here and received the following message: `root@falcon:/var/run/mysqld# dpk-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5
No command 'dpk-reconfigure' found, did you mean:
 Command 'dpkg-reconfigure' from package 'debconf' (main)
dpk-reconfigure: command not found`

Comment: sorry mistakenly written sir, use dpkg

Comment: Now I received the following message: `root@falcon:/var/run/mysqld# dpkg mysql-server-5.5
dpkg: error: need an action option

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !`

Comment: use with type `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5` sir

Comment: I ran the command and the message appeared: `root@falcon:/var/run/mysqld# sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: mysql-server-5.5 is broken or not fully installed`

Comment: you have a broken package sir, try `sudo apt-get -f install mysql-server-5.5` and reconfigure again sir

Comment: I ran the command and received the initial message: `Unable to set password for the MySQL "root" user An error occurred while setting the password for the MySQL administrative user. This may have happened because the account already has a password, or because of a communication problem with the MySQL server. You should check the account's password after the package`

Comment: Continuation of the trace: `start: Job failed to start invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed. dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server: mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however: Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet. dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure): dependency problems - leaving unconfigured`

Comment: Continuation of the trace: `No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure. Errors were encountered while processing: mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) W: Operation was interrupted before it could finish`

Comment: i think you need to remove mysql.cnf also my.cnf and run dpkg-reconfigure <package> again sir

Comment: i also used mysql-community-server ,when i had the same your issue, i just reinstall with `sudo apt-get purge --remove <package>` and remove all temporary files mysq and install it againl. also when i had mistakenly config file, i just run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure <package>` and i change that config. hope another have a new tricks sir

Comment: I'm going to try to complete the whole process again, but I'd already removed everything previously according to the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16178696/2918302

Comment: nice sir, i see you have mysql-server and mysql-server-5.5 , just choose one less sir

Comment: Really, you're right, abu-ahmed al-khatiri!

Comment: your link way is same with my older issue with my mysql-community-server issue, glad to hear your issue solved

Comment: @abu-ahmed al-khatiri, could you give me the link to your mysql-community-server issue, please?

Comment: no link sir, just i solve my self sir

Comment: Thank you very much, abu-ahmed al-khatiri, for all your help! I will continue to try to solve this problem. As soon as I can solve this problem, I will certainly post the answer to help other people with the same problem.

Comment: glad to hear your issue solved sir.